# Сортировка подмассивов в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

Имеется такая структура массива:

```
0: […]
    0: […]
        0: Object { x: 28716 }
        1: Object { y: 6057 }
        2: Object { square: 17749 }
    1: […]
        0: Object { x: 27664 }
        1: Object { y: 5693 }
        2: Object { square: 49878 }
    2: […]
        0: Object { x: 27777 }
        1: Object { y: 5137 }
        2: Object { square: 22012 }
1: […]
    0: […]
        0: Object { x: 4716 }
        1: Object { y: 6057 }
        2: Object { square: 749 }
    1: […]
        0: Object { x: 3664 }
        1: Object { y: 5593 }
        2: Object { square: 878 }
    2: […]
        0: Object { x: 13777 }
        1: Object { y: 1237 }
        2: Object { square: 29012 }
```

Как отсортировать каждый подмассив по убыванию по свойству square?

Чтобы получилось вот так:

```
0: […]
    0: […]
        0: Object { x: 27664 }
        1: Object { y: 5693 }
        2: Object { square: 49878 }
    1: […]
        0: Object { x: 27777 }
        1: Object { y: 5137 }
        2: Object { square: 22012 }
    2: […]
        0: Object { x: 28716 }
        1: Object { y: 6057 }
        2: Object { square: 17749 }
1: […]
    0: […]
        0: Object { x: 13777 }
        1: Object { y: 1237 }
        2: Object { square: 29012 }
    1: […]
        0: Object { x: 3664 }
        1: Object { y: 5593 }
        2: Object { square: 878 }
    2: […]
        0: Object { x: 4716 }
        1: Object { y: 6057 }
        2: Object { square: 749 }
```

Comment: Объединить вторую вложенность можно или каждый должен остаться где был, но сортировка общая для всех?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, лучшим вариантом будет заменить

```
0: […]
    0: […]
        0: Object { x: 27664 }
        1: Object { y: 5693 }
        2: Object { square: 49878 }
    1: […]
        0: Object { x: 27777 }
        1: Object { y: 5137 }
        2: Object { square: 22012 }
    2: […]
        0: Object { x: 28716 }
        1: Object { y: 6057 }
        2: Object { square: 17749 }
1: […]
    0: […]
        0: Object { x: 13777 }
        1: Object { y: 1237 }
        2: Object { square: 29012 }
    1: […]
        0: Object { x: 3664 }
        1: Object { y: 5593 }
        2: Object { square: 878 }
    2: […]
        0: Object { x: 4716 }
        1: Object { y: 6057 }
        2: Object { square: 749 }
```

на

```
0: […]
    0: Object {
         x: 27664,
         y: 5693,
         square: 49878
    },
    1: Object {
        x: 27664,
        y: 5693,
        square: 49878
    },
    2: Object {
         x: 27664,
         y: 5693,
         square: 49878
    }
1: […]
    0: Object {
         x: 27664,
         y: 5693,
         square: 49878
    },
    1: Object {
         x: 27664,
         y: 5693,
         square: 49878
    },
    2: Object {
         x: 27664,
         y: 5693,
         square: 49878
    }
```

и тогда функция сортировки будет выглядеть примерно так

```
for (var i = 0; i < tvoy_massiv.length; i++) {
    var item_i = tvoy_massiv[i];

    item_i.sort(function (a, b) {
      return b.square - a.square;
    });
}
console.log(tvoy_massiv);
```